# Где папка с созданными материалами в панели Joomla?

Tags: joomla, хостинг

Кто знает, в какой папке на хостинге сохраняется созданный материал в панели Joomla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

но сохраняется не в папке, а в базе данных в таблице префикс_content